# React - Dynamic Image loading using props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am attempting to load an image with the src of the image being stored in the `this.props.src`. The `this.props.src` outputs the correct name of the img file I would like to load: "koolImg". I am importing the file by: `import koolImg from '../img/koolImg.png'.` This is the current setup: `<img src={this.props.src} alt="noLoad"/>`. However, no image is loaded, just the "alt" value is displayed. What am I missing? I am new to React.

[image]

I created this react app using the `npx create-react-app koolImgApp` command, thus using webpack. Running on React 16.4.1 and using Google Chrome 67.

Comment: Could you include the code you have written so far in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`koolImg` is just a string which can't be used directly as a `src` attribute of an `img` element.

You could map this to the image you have imported by storing the imported image variable in an object, and then accessing that with your `src` prop string:

**Example**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import koolImg from '../img/koolImg.png';

const images = {
  koolImg
};

class ImgSrc extends Component {
  render() {
    return <img src={images[this.props.src]} />;
  }
}
```